# Xamarin android app: backgroundImage causing crashs and performance issues

Tags: android, xamarin, memory, xamarin.forms

I'm experiencing a weird issue. My app has a splashscreen and after loaded it shows the first page that is a login page. If I don't put any background color at login's stacklayout, the background image of splash keeps being showed all the time. So I did this:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"   x:Class="App.Login"
         BackgroundImage="background.jpg">
```

background.jpg is setted as an EmbededResource and its size is 78kb

That solved the problem and a new background is showed as expected. But with that, a new problem has surged:

with BackgroundImage option the app runs very well on MotoG5(android 7.0 nougat), on Asus zenphone things gets very slowly, even the virtual keyboard takes a long time to appear if touch on any entry component and finally on Galaxy S6(also android 7.0 nougat) the app shows splash screen and crashs suddenly.

If I remove BackgroundImage option and recompile, everything works well on the 3 specified devices.

I'm new on this but I think there isn't too much code at Login.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="App.Login"
             BackgroundImage="background.jpg">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Fill" HorizontalOptions="Fill">
            <Image Source="logomarca.png" HorizontalOptions="Center" Margin="0, 50, 0, 0" />
            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Margin="25">
                <Label Text="Usuário" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" TextColor="#FF7500" />
                <Entry x:Name="usuario" Placeholder="seu@email.com" FontSize="Small" TextColor="#FF7500" />
                <Label Text="Senha" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Margin="0, 20, 0, 0" TextColor="#FF7500" />
                <Entry x:Name="senha" Placeholder="******" IsPassword="True" FontSize="Small" Margin="0" TextColor="#FF7500" />
                <Button x:Name="botaoEntrar" Text="Entrar" Clicked="BotaoEntrar_Clicked" TextColor="White" BackgroundColor="#ff9600" />
                <Button x:Name="facebookLogin" Text="Facebook" Clicked="BotaoEntrar_Clicked" TextColor="White" BackgroundColor="#4267b2" />
            </StackLayout>
            <Label x:Name="statusLogin" Text="Validando informações..." HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" TextColor="Green" FontSize="Micro" Margin="0, 0, 0, 40" IsVisible="False" />
            <Label x:Name="rodapeLink" Text="Ainda não tem uma conta? Crie agora." HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" TextColor="#5b93fc" FontSize="Default" Margin="0, 0, 0, 20" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

logomarca.png has only 73kb

I tried to set Java Maximum Heap to 1G but no success.

Are you seeing any problem or could give some tip of how is the best way to handle this?  I don't know how to debug this because Moto G5 is using the same android(nougat 7.0) and everything is allright.

Comment: Did you try changing the background.jpg to a .png extension file and add it?

Comment: When you say it crashes, do you have more information on the crash?

Comment: @hashimks yes... it was originally a png file, I changed to jpg to down its size.